# Google Cloud API Speech-to-text Go program returns "Provided scope(s) are not authorized" when nodejs succeeds

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform

I'm starting with the Go libraries calling the Speech-to-Text API as described in https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/libraries#client-libraries-usage-go .. I've created a new Service Worker, given it Owner role, and set the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to point to the credentials file.  However when it calls the `Recognize()` function an Error is returned:

```
2021/07/09 16:58:02 failed to recognize: rpc error: code = PermissionDenied desc = Provided scope(s) are not authorized
```

As a sanity check, I can copy-paste the Node library code from that docs page into a fresh node script, set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS variable to the same credentials file, and the test code runs OK:

```
$ node quickstart.js
Transcription: how old is the Brooklyn Bridge
```

So the very basic Nodejs client sample code works fine, but the Go sample code does not.

I've tried the storage API using the same Go project, and find I can enumerate storage buckets, get Attrs on Objects, and upload files OK, using the same service worker credentials, so I am sure it's finding the credentials.

If I step into the calls, inside `NewClient()` I can see it's calling into `defaultGRPCClientOptions` and `internaloption.WithDefaultScopes(DefaultAuthScopes()...),` to set  setting the scope "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform" which I think is all correct.

I'm running go 1.16.5, my `go.mod` has:

```
require (
    cloud.google.com/go v0.86.0 // indirect
    cloud.google.com/go/storage v1.16.0 // indirect
    firebase.google.com/go/v4 v4.6.0 // indirect
    github.com/boj/redistore v0.0.0-20180917114910-cd5dcc76aeff // indirect
    github.com/gin-gonic/contrib v0.0.0-20201101042839-6a891bf89f19 // indirect
    github.com/gin-gonic/gin v1.7.2 // indirect
    github.com/golang/gddo v0.0.0-20210115222349-20d68f94ee1f // indirect
    github.com/gorilla/mux v1.8.0 // indirect
    github.com/gorilla/sessions v1.2.1 // indirect
    github.com/mattn/go-isatty v0.0.12 // indirect
    github.com/sirupsen/logrus v1.8.1 // indirect
    golang.org/x/oauth2 v0.0.0-20210628180205-a41e5a781914 // indirect
    google.golang.org/api v0.50.0 // indirect
    google.golang.org/genproto v0.0.0-20210708141623-e76da96a951f // indirect
    google.golang.org/protobuf v1.27.1 // indirect
)
```

What can I do to investigate this scopes error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we ran into this just now and saw your post. It seems the new version `cloud.google.com/go/storage v1.16.0 // indirect` is the problem. we forced 1.15.0 which was working for us and it continues to work. we were going nuts thinking it was a permission problem. Maybe it is if they changed what's required. I would force v1.15.0 and see if that fixes it for you.

Comment: Thanks @Jon .. but I was talking about the speech-to-text API.  The Storage API is working fine for me.  Are we talking about the same thing? :)  Were you getting this permission problem calling the storage API?

Comment: Update: I forced the storage library to 1.15.0 anyway with `go get cloud.google.com/go/storage@v1.15.0` but the same permissions error comes back from the Recognize call.

Comment: Update 2: Aha! I dug into the https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go CHANGES.md for any changes affecting the speech API and tried a few, adn this seems to have fixed things: `go get cloud.google.com/go@v0.82.0` ... `go get cloud.google.com/go/speech/apiv1@v0.82.0` ... `go get google.golang.org/api/iterator@v0.46.0` ... `go mod download cloud.google.com/go/storage` .. each command was prompted by the compiler as I tried to build and it said something was missing.  So, Thanks!  I've no idea why the latest version doesn't work, but downgrading to 0.82.0 has made the error go away.